# How to make an :hover sub-menu not disapear when not pointing the main menu anymore ? (HTML - CSS)

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

My drop-down menu disappears when I stop pointing at the main menu with my mouse. I'd like the submenu to appear only when I hover over the menu with my mouse, but I don't want it to disappear when I scroll down.
Here is my code :

```
 <!-- Barre de menu -->
    <nav class="menu-bar">
        <ul class="main-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
            <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Prédateurs</a>
                <div class="sub-menu-container">
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <!-- Ajoutez ici vos 10 sous-menus pour Prédateurs -->
                    <!--exemple d'un sous-menu-->
                    <li><a href="#">Lion</a></li> <!--il faut mettre le lien de la page à la place du dièse-->
                    <li><a href="#">Léopard</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Herbivores</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                <!-- Ajoutez ici vos 10 sous-menus pour Herbivores -->
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Oiseaux</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                <!-- Ajoutez ici vos 2 sous-menus pour Oiseaux -->
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

```
/* Styles pour la barre de menu */
.menu-bar {
    background-color: #262633;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /*utilisé pour centrer horizontalement le contenu*/
    align-items: center; /*utilisé pour centrer verticalement le contenu*/
}

/* Styles pour les liens des menus principaux */
.main-menu li {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Styles pour les sous-menus */
.submenu {
    display: none;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    background-color: #262633;
}

.has-submenu:hover .submenu { /*pour les sous-menus s'affichent quand on survole*/
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.submenu a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Pseudo-élément pour la flèche */
.has-submenu > a::after { /*Si je mets pas le ">", cela ajoute également une flèche aux sous-menus*/
    content: "\25BE"; /* Code Unicode pour la flèche vers le bas */
    margin-left: 7px; /* Espacement entre le texte et la flèche */
    color: white; /* Couleur de la flèche */
}
```

I tried averything. The only thing I have avoided is javascript cause I would prefer to avoid it due to the ability from users to block it on their navigator.